# PostgreSQL - copy from binary UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: postgresql

I want to copy data from one PostgreSQL server to another.

I did: `\copy (select * from table_name) to 'table_name.bin' BINARY`

Then I wanted to do `\copy table_name from 'table_name.bin' with BINARY` but I get

```sql
COPY from stdin failed: error from Python: UnicodeDecodeError - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 7: invalid start byte
CONTEXT:  COPY table_name, line 1
```

Comment: 1) From [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html): *The binary format option causes all data to be stored/read as binary format rather than as text. It is somewhat faster than the text and CSV formats, but a binary-format file is less portable across machine architectures and PostgreSQL versions. Also, the binary format is very data type specific; ...*.  Why are you using `BINARY`? Try with either the text of CSV format.